# Offline Word Processor / WYSIWYG Editor for non-HTML savvy users

Tags: html, wysiwyg, offline, html-editor

Due to a new web site and CMS system, I'm dealing with multiple users making content changes to our site. Many of them are trying to copy and paste content from MS Word and other Office products which, as any web developer knows, is a nightmare.

What I'm looking for is a simple **offline** Word Processor or WYSIWYG editor that I can ask people to use instead of Word in cases where they aren't going to be composing their changes directly on our site.

Basic requirements:

- It should be simple to use. I do not need any advanced features. Basically just a word processor that generates valid HTML.
- Freeware or open source would be nice
- It would be a bonus if it also had a "paste-from-Word" feature
- I am *not* looking for a MS Office replacement as that will never get approved. I need a supplemental editor for our web content editors.

Our environment is mostly Windows Vista/7, though we do have a small base of Mac users as well.

Based on my searches, the most frequent answer I see is NVU, but quite honestly that is too complex for my users since I don't need a whole site editor, file manager, or web publishing software - just the ability to create/edit simple HTML documents.

*Yes, I know this technically isn't a programming question, but I'm sure it is relevant to a lot of programmers and web developers.*

Answer (score 0):

You can open a WYSIWYG from a local html file. If you don't want to do this through the normal browser, you can do it through an embedded web browser in your application. Check Qt, its a framework that can show web pages (local ones too) using WebKit.

Comment: I don't want to just display the files - I want to edit them. I also don't want to do the edits in a browser, as the users are already submitting their changes in a WYSIWYG control. I want the users to be able to edit, save, and share the content offline BEFORE submitting it to the CMS.

Comment: @Rick: this method can show web pages offline as well. you can add edit, save and share to the embedded web page using WYSIWYG control with no connection whatsoever to the net or your site, they don't even have to know its all done in html.